# Cocos2d bounding according to the direction of moving

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is my first time to post something here. :).

I have searched for this problem many times even in this stackoverflow, but still no luck.

I have one question about bounding between two objects in Cocos2d. To make it clear, let me give you an example. There are two objects, Line and Square Box. Square Box size is about 32 x 32. Line is movable object where as Square Box is static. The way line is moving is up 45 degree of the horizontal line. When the line hits the square box, it must reflect down 90 degree and so on.

My problem is I want to make the line reflect just like the light hits the mirror. So when the line hits square box, the line must reflect according to where it hits. For instance, during the line is moving up 45, if the line hits the left-face square box, it will reflect 270 degree. If the line hits the bottom-face square box, it will reflect 90 degree, and so on... The moving direction must change accordingly also.

Sorry about my English... :D.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to analyse separately all edges of the box to determive which of them your line crosses first.

If you have any object and you want it to reflect on collisions with other object, you can use box2d. It will calculate all for you. You just have to setup it and synchronize your sprite's positions with the bodies in the physical world.

Comment: Hi Morion <br /><br />Thank you for your reply<br /><br />Your first solution is quite complicated, however; your second one is quite interesting, but I am new to Box2D. Could you give me any example just for collision using Box2D?

Comment: you can find tutorials via google. here one of them http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls